# how to assign variable to json reply

Tags: php, json

I want to assign a variable to my json reply. I want to use that variable to echo only the selected data

This is my reply:

`{"code":"202","message":"Accepted","data":{"resultMap":{"D1509~H24":{"AppDay":"*","HosTown":"Colombo","SpecName":"Physiotherapist","HosName":"Western Infirmary Hospital (Pvt) Ltd","SpecializationId":"34","HosCode":"H24","AppDate":"Any","DocName":"MR M. HAJITH","DoctorNo":"D1509"},"D0625~H08":{"AppDay":"*","HosTown":"Colombo","SpecName":"Physiotherapist","HosName":"Park Hospital (Pvt) Ltd ","SpecializationId":"34","HosCode":"H08","AppDate":"Any","DocName":"MR JALIYA UDUWELLA","DoctorNo":"D0625"},"D1762~H16":`

This is my code but I am getting an error message:

> Undefined index: resultMap in C:\wamp\www\echanalling\test.php

on

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
require 'gettoken1.php';                                
            {
$baseurl = 'http://202.124.173.189/api/v1/doctorAvailability';    
$curl = curl_init($baseurl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"Authorization: Bearer $atoken")); 

// Set the POST arguments to pass to the Sugar server
$rawPOSTdata = array(
    "type" => "private",
    "hosID" => $_POST['hosMaptxt'],
    "specID" => $_POST['specialityMaptxt'],
     "date" => $_POST['date'],
    "name" => '%'.$_POST['docname'].'%'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($rawPOSTdata));    

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if (!$response)
    {
    die("Connection Failure.\n");

$result = json_decode($response,true);    

 $json=$result['data']['resultMap'];
$html=array();
$output[]="<table><tr> ";
foreach($result['resultMap']as $data)
{
    $output.="<td>".$data['SpecName']."</td>";
    $output.="<td>".$data['HosName']."</td>";
    $output.="<td>".$data['DocName']."</td>";
    $output.="<td>".$data['DoctorNo']."</td>";
    $output.="<td>".$data['AppDay']."</td>";
    $output.="<td>".$data['HosTown']."</td>";
            }
            $output .="</tr></table>";
            echo $output;        
}

curl_close($curl);
if ( isset($result->error) )
    {
    die($result->error_message."\n");
    } 
 }    
?>
```

Comment: Show how you receive `$result`

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't show sufficient complete and precise code to be sure, but at a first glance we can guess that:

1. `$result = json_decode($response,true);` is where you get the contents of your JSON data
2. `foreach($result['resultMap']as $data)` is where you get the error

So from #1 above comes that what you get in `$result` should look like:

```
[
  "code" => "202",
  "message" => "Accepted",
  "data" => [
    "resultMap" => [
      "D1509~H24" => [
        "AppDay" => "*",
        ...
      ],
      "D0625~H08" => [
        "AppDay" => "*",
        ...
      ],
      ...
    ]
  ]
]
```

Then from #2 above it's perfectly normal you get an error trying to access `$result['resultMap']`, which is not a 1st-level key of `$result`.

To access this part of the data you should write `$result['data']['resultMap']` instead.